# JavaScript ASP.NET Poor Performance

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, performance, timing

I have just started collecting metrics on a website that I am working on. In order to monitor the server runtime for page loads, I have the stopwatch in the PageInit and PreRender. The server side seems to be running relatively well (max of a few seconds).

The front end is running extremely slow but only occasionally. I am using window.performance.timing to measure this. From navigationStart to loadEventEnd, I have gotten some really high numbers (close to 80 seconds, not ms). However, when I break these numbers down, I am not seeing where the slowness is actually coming from. I have measured everything on the below chart individually and they don't even come close to adding up to the total page load time. Any ideas where the slowness is coming from?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried opening Developer Tools (F12) in Chrome on the Network tab to see how long each request for the web page takes.  It may be that you have too many resources (use a bundle), or that maybe the rendering takes too long (main page request).  Either way, it would be where I would start

Comment: I have and it is coming from the ASP.NET page. However, when I measure the ASP.NET time using a stopwatch (started in PageInit and stopped in PreRender) everything seems fine. Any idea where to go from here? It's somewhere in the ASP.NET lifecycle but I can't seem to pinpoint where. Especially since it isn't between init and pre-render.

Comment: Have you tried measuring the time the controller takes to collect / parse data. I would expect thats the next thing to look at. It may also be worth while turning on exception handling for all, if you end up throwing a lot of exceptions (even if they are caught) it can cause your application to run slowly

Comment: It's not MVC so no controller. It is happening on the server side I think but I can't track it down. How would I measure the performance hit of exception handling?